# Is using `\input{}` in a user defined package to partition it into smaller ones a correct way?

Tags: package-writing

I am writing  my own package called `mylisting.sty` to format code inclusion for languanges: LaTeX, PSTricks, C#, and XML.

To maintain `mylisting.sty` cleaner, I make a separate file for each language:

- `LaTeXSettings.tex` for LaTeX,
- `PSTricksSettings.tex` for PSTricks,
- `CSharpSettings.tex` for CSharp, and
- `XMLSettings.tex` for XML.

Is it correct to use `\input{}` within `mylisting.sty` to import `LaTeXSettings.tex`, `PSTricksSettings.tex`, `CSharpSettings.tex` and `XMLSettings.tex`?

Or you have a better method to accomplish this objective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK. You can use whatever file name (or extensions) you like. An extensible method is, like many packages use, to use a set of configuration/definition files. For example, in `graphics` package macro `\Gin@driver` is the driver file. The code is used as

```
\DeclareOption{dvips}{\def\Gin@driver{dvips.def}}
\DeclareOption{pdftex}{\def\Gin@driver{pdftex.def}}
% ...
\input{\Gin@driver}
```

Comment: Let's use your sample above in our discussion. Do I have to specify `ProvideFile{dvips.def}` in `dvips.def` ?

Comment: No, you needn't. See `clsguide` for more information.

Comment: but you should. then it is listed in file list which makes sense if one has an error in his code.